# Component Presention Preview configured timeout (00:01:00)

Tags: web8.5

I am getting Page Component presenation  component preview configured timeout (00:01:00) issue.

Any one have idea how to resolve this issue.

> 80040356)  This request operation sent to
>   net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/201603/netTcp did not receive a
>   reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00).  The time allotted to
>   this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  This may
>   be because the
>
> This request operation sent to
>   net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/201603/netTcp did not receive a
>   reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00).  The time allotted to
>   this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  This may
>   be because the service is still processing the operation or because
>   the service was unable to send a reply message.  Please consider
>   increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to
>   IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure
>   that the service is able to connect to the client.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have any custom event system modules or UI extensions enabled in your implementation?

Comment: Also, can you try to increase your timeouts per the following KB article and update your question? This will help isolate issue with SDL vs infrastructure as well.
https://gateway.sdl.com/articles/SolutionArticles/000003814?articleName=000004535